# Como pintar las keys de un objeto en Rectjs

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api, objeto

Hola tengo una api que necesito consumir, pero antes debo pintar las keys que tiene en unos botones, por ahora necesito ayuda en cuanto a como puedo pintar las keys para generar mis botones pero una sola vez, lo intente y se repite por cada iteracion que hago. Por favor si me pueden ayudar.

Aqui esta mi codigo donde intento pintar las keys:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { getData } from '../functions/functions';

const CreateReport = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    //postData()
    getData(setData)
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {!data ? 'Cargando...' : data.map((el, index) => {
          return <p key={index}>{Object.keys(el)}</p>
        })}
      </div>

    </>
  )
}

export default CreateReport;
```

Este es mi codigo de la api que estoy consumiendo

```
import axios from 'axios';
export const getData = (state) => {

  const config = {
    method: 'get',
    url: 'http://xxxxxxxxxxx/cubo/api/ventas?empresa=63&periodo=202202',
    headers: {
      'token': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    }
  };

  axios(config)
    .then(response => state(response.data.data))
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
}
```

y aqui les muestro una imagen de lo que se pinta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y esto es lo que quiero lograr hacer >>>>>>>>>
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco me puedan ayudar o compartir recursos que me orienten

Comment: Puedes poner un ejemplo de la estructura? cómo se ve el array que te trae la api

Comment: @JorgeAlmada esta es la estructura de mi api   [{....}, {....}, {....}, {....}, {....}, {....},{....}, {....},{....}, {....},{....}, {....},{....}, {....}]

Comment: Abre los objetos, y muestra una foto de los objetos, para ver las propiedades

Comment: @JorgeAlmada logre hacer lo que quiero pero en javascript, ahora necesito pasarlo a react, >>>>>>>>>>>>>> const data_api = await fetch(url, requestOptions)
  const res = await data_api.json();
  const res_data = res.data
  
  const arr = Object.entries(res_data);

  const arr1 = Object.keys(arr[1][1])
  
  let boton = ``;
  arr1.forEach((el) => {
    console.log(el)
    boton += `
     <div class='containerGame'>
           <button>${el}</button>
       </div> `
  });
  document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = boton;